# how do I import my intellij project settings on a groovy script in terminal

Tags: macos, groovy, intellij-idea, terminal

I have a single script in a project in intellij that I want to run in my mac terminal.  I can run the script but I am getting errors where it can't find the JAR files I added as a module.  There are a lot of dependencies, so I was wondering how can I add my intellij project settings to calling my groovy script.  Right now all I have is this:

```
groovy CreateReport.groovy
```

Comment: You may consider using [Grape](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all you need to do is dump your libraries into the GROOVY_HOME/lib directory, where GROOVY_HOME is where you have defined your groovy environment variables to be.

http://dustinwhitney.blogspot.com/2008/03/groovy-classpath.html